# Invoking EJB on 1.6 from client on 1.5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, java-6, java-5

I have a Glassfish v3 server running a set of EJBs (under java 1.6 obviously).

I have another machine on top of which I have a  host java 1.5 - none J2EE - process (i can't change that).
The question is how to perform invocation of the EJB from the java 1.5 client?

Thanks in advance,
Asaf

Answer (score 0):

> The question is how to perform invocation of the EJB from the java 1.5 client?

Using Java 1.5 on the client side shouldn't be an issue. See [How do I access a Remote EJB component from a stand-alone java client?](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB) in the EJB FAQ for general instructions.

Comment: The problem is that in order to create such a standalone client, I have to perform Step 3.  Include the appropriate GlassFish .jars in the java client's classpath. And Then i'm getting the following exception: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file....... because the java client is a 1.5 and the glassfish jars were built using 1.6 bytecode.

Comment: @user496981: Hmm... That's new to me. I'm pretty sure this was working with the prelude version. Maybe things changed, I'll have to dig this a bit then.